# How to handle the screen "flickering" after back navigation?

Tags: java, android

So we have a legacy project, where we don't use the Navigation component, databinding etc...

When I navigate from Fragment A to fragment B, I use this code:

```
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(enter, exit, popEnter, popExit)
                    .replace(getFragmentContainerId(), fragment, fragmentTag)
                    .addToBackStack(backStackTag)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

The problem is, when I press the back button, and the popBackStack method called, the previous fragment (Fragment A) flashing/flickering. This is because all of the lifecycle method runs (onResume, onCreateView, onViewCreated), and in onViewCreated I have a bunch of observers which update the ui.

I tried to use the addFragment, instead of replace, and it solved the flickering, but it caused an another problem, because in this case, the onResume method wont get called, and it contains some important logic.

So my question is, how could I resolve this thing?
I have 1 possible solution in my mind, that I create a callback function, and in Fragment B onPause method I call it, and I put all of the functions from onResume into this callback fun. In this case I have to use addFragment instead of replace.

It is working, but I believe it isn't the best solution, because Fragment B onPause method can be invoked not just then, when I press the back button.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the reason, and the answer as well.

So one of the LiveData updated the ui as I mentioned, so I created some kind of SingleEvent<> class, and wrap up this liveData. So if I return to Fragment A although the liveData fires, but it wont do anything, because this value was previously handled.